# Tiddlywiki Custom Field Sort As Number

Tags: javascript, sorting, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

I'm making a TiddlyWiki where some of the tiddlers contain the following fields: `age` `year` `month` `date` corresponding to the date of the tiddler in a fictional universe (hence I can't use the existing date fields, the calendar is different).

I have this code that creates a list and sorts tiddlers more or less correctly by `age`, `year`, `month`, `date` in that order:

```
<$list filter="[tag[history]] [tag[progress]] +[!sort[date]!sort[month]!sort[year]!sort[age]]">
<$link>{{!!title}}</$link> | <span style="font-weight: bold;">Age:</span> {{!!age}} <span style="font-weight: bold;">Year:</span> {{!!year}} <span style="font-weight: bold;">Month:</span> {{!!month}} <span style="font-weight: bold;">Date:</span> {{!!date}}<br>
</$list>
```

But when I have a field that is say `month:11` it gets sorted after `month:1` and before `month:2` because it's being evaluated and sorted as text.

So my question comes down to how can I force `sort[]` to treat its parameter like an integer, or how can I tell TiddlyWiki what kind of data I'm storing in my custom fields?

### Solution

Use `nsort[]` instead of `sort[]`

Comment: You could add the solution as an answer and mark the question as answered. It's totally legit (https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).